# Windows Phone 8.1 + SignalR - receiving push notifications on background/shut down

Tags: signalr, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm writing Windows Phone 8.1 application and I want to receive the push notifications from the SinglaR server. It is working, but only when the application is on the foreground.
How can I receive the notification when the application is in the background or shut down?

Does *PushNotificationTrigger* catches the notification from the SignalR? Or does the *PushNotificationTrigger* work only with WNS?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR offers realtime connection and data exchange *while* the application is active and connected. Once application goes to background it is effectively closed and all active connections are closed.

If you want to send push notifications, that is something OS offers and is not something you do via your own framework. If you want to receive notifications while the application is closed, you need to use the standard push functionality built into the platform. And which is completely separated from SignalR.

You can still use your website to send push notifications though.